# 12.04 not mounting Kindle 3

Tags: 12.04, kindle

I've tried plugging in my Kindle (3rd generation-keyboard), but nothing happens when I do.  It's not seeing the device anywhere.  I've tried re-booting the kindle while plugged in, I've installed Calibre and I've tried a couple of other suggestions I've seen mentioned in the forums.  Still nothing.  Any suggestions or anyone else with the same problem?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

After connecting the kindle to your computer

the last lines of /var/log/syslog 
should contain something like this:

```
[39034.269113] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[39034.271098] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 1982464 512-byte logical blocks: (1.01 GB/968 M
```

Since the Kindle devices behave like ordinary mass storage device.

If nothing is to be found your device is not being detected at all. Does anything change on the kindle itself when you connect it? The screen should change into a  docking /  charging screen.

You might have a broken port on the kindle or perhaps the usb cable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I ended up getting a new kindle though b/c I found one for such a great price.  The old one was having other issues, too.